# python script running with only with interactive nvidia docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker, nvidia-docker

If intend to run a python script using the following command

```
nvidia-docker run -v /home/$USER/:/home/$USER doc/deep_rl python script.py
```

This throws an error

> No module named chester.run_exp

However if I first run the docker interactively by adding `-it` flag

```
nvidia-docker run -it -v /home/$USER/:/home/$USER doc/deep_rl
```

and once inside the docker, i do

```
python script.py
```

everything runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command.

```
nvidia-docker run -it  --rm -v /home/harjatin/:/home/harjatin harjatin/deep_rl python script.py
```

It will work.

Comment: The same as before. No difference